# I know how it looks in SQL, but I need it in HQL and am stuck

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Consider I have such SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.table2_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.value = 'something' OR t1.value = 'something';
```

I need the same thing done in HQL query.
More info: Say I have classes *Table1* and *Table2* both having field named *value* and *Table1* having a field *table2* of class *Table2*. What I want is to get a list of *Table1* objects that have certain *value* or it's member *table2* has certain *value* and I know that *table2* field might be null.

I have tried to formulate the question as clearly as I could without trying to explain every single way I tried to do that without success. Sorry if it is not very clear.

Comment: Your query looks strange, you have not joined your tables. I surgest this: SELECT * FROM table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.table2_id = t2.id 
where (t2.value = 'something' 
      OR t1.value = 'something')

Comment: @t-clausen.dk It's an implicit join (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join ).

Comment: @Borealid ok, tell me how many rows do you think will be returned if table1 value = 'something' ? Answer: this will return as many rows as exists in table2

Comment: @t-clausen.dk That's not correct. If `table1.value='something'` for all rows, the query as written will return the number of rows in `table1` TIMES the number of rows in `table2`. Joins are fundamentally cross products. Why don't you post an answer correcting the query and writing it in HQL?

Comment: @Borealid you are right, then again you proved that the tables was not joined as my initial claim stated. I didnt post it as an answer because i dont know what HQL is

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Of course the tables are joined. The result set contains information *from both tables*. By definition, that is a join. Take a look at the link I sent.

Comment: I might be better to split this into two queries. You don't say what the underlying RDBMS is, but (for example) SQL Server won't nescessarialy pick an optimal index or query plan with what is effectively) a cross-table `OR` condition. Ultimately it depends on the indexes, but you may well get better perf by splitting it in two and eradicating the `OR`. This may make it easier to move into HQL then as well (yes, I know this is unrelated to the question, but it's just an observation that may help you think about the problem in a different way as well).

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thanks for your input. You are right, the query provided is wrong, I will fix it in the question as soon as I finished checking all the information I got from everyone here.

Comment: @ChrisJ you have noted some interesting points. Thank you for that. But there are reasons mostly related to paging mechanism used that forces me to do it in one query or start messing with the current design (and that is I would rather avoid doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example:

```
select t1 from Table1 as t1 left outer join t1.table2 as t2
where t1.value = :value or t2.value = :value
```

Additional note:
If using grails one has to use *executeQuery* method as *findAll* will not be enough.

There may be other solutions that I do not know. If you want to share a better solution, please do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of the problem in the question, I assume that you have a parent class Table1 and a child class Table2. Table1 has a member table2 of type Table2. In this case, I believe, the appropriate HQL should look like this:

```
from Table1 t1 where t1.value = 'something' or t1.table2.value = 'something'
```

Comment: Classes are not in parent child relation. Table1 only has member of Table2 class. In other words _Table1_ class contains _Long id, String value, Table2 table2_ fields. Your suggested query would produce similar SQL to this: `select t1.* from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.table2_id=t2.id and (t2.value=? or t1.value=?)` and that does not return table1 rows where table2_id is null.

Comment: @Aidas: Good catch! Gotta use left outer join. But I can see that you already figured it out: from Table1 t1 left outer join t1.table2 t2 where t1.value = 'something' or t2.value = 'something'.